# Swagger autogen - overwriting implementation code

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen

Does anyone here have a good strategy for dealing with a changing API spec?

API change -> regenerate code -> implement changes.

I'm thinking generating Java interfaces and having separate class files which implement these interfaces. Any interface mismatches will show up in IDE (e.g. IntelliJ)

Right now if I do the implementation, the files where I wrote the implementation gets overwritten...

Answer (score 1):

My generated swagger Code will be put under src/gen/Java. Everytime i generate the whole folder will be deleted. That way the implementation of the interfaces will not be overwritten. Also i do not commit the gen folder.

**EDIT**

To illustrate it a little bit more have a look at the templates: https://github.com/Mehtrick/swagger-templates

The important ones are the api and apicontroller.mustache

The generated controller classes look like this

```
@RestController
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
public class UsersApiController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersApi UsersApiService;

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()  and hasAuthority('USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/current", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getCurrentUser() throws Exception {
        return UsersApiService.getCurrentUser();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> registerUser(

            @Valid @RequestBody User body

    ) throws Exception {
        return UsersApiService.registerUser(body);
    }

}
```

And then the generated UsersApi looks like this:

```
public interface UsersApi {

    /**
     * Loads the current user
     */
    ResponseEntity<User> getCurrentUser() throws Exception;

    /**
     * Registers a new user
     */
    ResponseEntity<Void> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody User body) throws Exception;

}
```

All I have to do is to implement the generated api interfaces as spring components.

These classes are generated from Swagger with this gradle plugin:

https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin

The build config looks like this:

```
ext {
    swaggeryaml = file("${projectDir}/swagger/swagger.yaml")
}

apply plugin: "org.hidetake.swagger.generator"

validateSwagger {
  inputFile = swaggeryaml
}


generateSwaggerCode {
  language = 'spring'
  inputFile = swaggeryaml
  components = ['models','apis']
  configFile = file("${swaggerconfigpath}")
  templateDir = file("${projectDir}/swagger/templates")
}
```

In this example the normal spring-swagger-codegen is used but with my customized templates under `${projectDir}/swagger/templates`

The buildscript is configured to move the generated files to `src/gen/java` and before that it deletes the whole `src/gen/java` folder

```
task cleanSwagger(type: Delete){
  delete "${projectDir}/src/gen/java/"
}

task moveSwagger(type: Copy){
  dependsOn "generateSwaggerCode"
  from "${buildDir}/swagger-code/src/main/java"
  into "${projectDir}/src/gen/java"
}
```

The build tasks are called when:

- the java code compiles (like on a ci-server)
- The IDE classpath (in my case Eclipse) is initialized

`compileJava.dependsOn swaggerGen`

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you manually copy and paste all implementations? My API spec is long... Have you ever implemented interfaces generated by swagger-codegen?

Comment: I refactored the templates a little. The API Controllers only calls the api Interface which are injected in the Controller. That way i just have to implement the API Interface as spring component. I use a gradle plugin to generate swagger. The plguin gives the option to configure the generator output. So everything happens automatically

Comment: This sounds like what I need to do. How did you set up this workflow?